# How can i make the row visible in small devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have changed the margin in the row in the CSS file but it wont applied in small devices

```
<body style="background-color: #353839;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 class="text-center mt-2" style="color: white;">Cyber Cloud</h1>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="row  r1 " style="background-color: black; ">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <h3 class="text-center" style="color: white;">Join Now</h3>
                <p class="text-center" style="color: white;">And Start Buying Games</p>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-12 r2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/>

                </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.r1{


    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 500px;
    

    
}
```

I have tried to apply bootstrap responsive CSS(added d-none d-lg-block) yet it doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

try to use media queries in css and set the display width of a device, use developer tools to change display width to simulate a device

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
.r1{
margin-left: 500px;
margin-right: 500px;
}
}
```

hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Bootstrap 4 and 5 give you the ability to display or not to display an element.
I added d-md-none in that row you want to show in the small device, and it will not show on the wide devices.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 class="text-center mt-2" style="color: black;">Cyber Cloud</h1>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="row  d-md-none" style="background-color: black; ">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <h3 class="text-center" style="color: white;">Join Now</h3>
                <p class="text-center" style="color: white;">And Start Buying Games</p>                                        
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-12 r2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/>

                </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want the out put for small and large  both

Comment: d-md-none will not display from (768px) and above. and d-sm-none will not display from (540px) and above. so if you want to display the row under ( 540px) do this: d-sm-none. And don't forget to upvote if you find it helpful, my friend :)

Comment: if you want to display it on a large device, you can do this: d-lg-flex.